# Python script no longer working

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have the following python script that is no longer working.  It ran when I first did this, but I ran it again after a few months of not touching it, and now I am getting the following error: **ImportError: No module named mpl_toolkits.mplot3d**

Like I said, I didn't edit anything in this script since it has worked months ago.  I checked the import statements, and they seem to be correct.  I'm not sure what is going on.  I tried finding a solution online, but I was unsuccessful.  I realize that this is a pretty hard question to answer, but I thought I would give it a shot.  I am totally stumped.  Thank you for any help you can give.

This script just makes a window pop up with a multi variable function plotted.  What it does isn't really important though.  I think I adapted it from a tutorial I found online.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

def fun(x, y):
  return x**2 + y

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
x = y = np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, 0.05)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
zs = np.array([fun(x,y) for x,y in zip(np.ravel(X), np.ravel(Y))])
Z = zs.reshape(X.shape)

ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)

ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')
```

Comment: Do you have a file named mpl_toolkits?

Comment: I was using python2 to run it, but I must have used pip3 to install the modules.  When I used python 3, everything worked.

Comment: python 2 & 3 will install modules in different locations. You may want to install modules using python 2 and see if it works.